# Make the progress bar move

Tags: html, css

I want to make a html progress bar so i used the below code but it is static, anyway to make it move by a javascript variable or something else?
I used `document.getElementById("progress-inner").style.width = percent;` but it works once.

## html

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:100" id="progress-outer">
    <div id="progress-inner"></div>
</div>
```

## css

```css
progress-outer {
    background: #333;
    -webkit-border-radius: 13px;
    height: 10px;
    width: 70%;
    padding: 3px;
}

progress-inner {
    background: orange;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;
}
```

Comment: U'll need some javascript

Comment: Can you please post some code that you have tried?  There are many good tutorials online that will help you start.

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/#indeterminate

Comment: You should check out jquery. Also, how are you planning to know how much of the progress is completed?

Comment: the question has been updated

Comment: @Skarlinski I have percent variable

Comment: @AmirArcane : Have you seen [Progressbar](http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/)??

Comment: If you're targeting WebKit based browsers, 1) [`border-radius`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=border-radius) has dropped vender prefix long since; 2) [`<progress> element`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=progressmeter) has been supported quite well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the following is just sample of it.. enhance it.

```
i = 1;
window.setInterval(
    function(){
        i++;
        $('.progress-inner').css({ width : i + "%" });
    },
    200);
```

Comment: Note that he did not include jquery in his question.

Comment: he probably didn' mean that :)